# London Heathrow airport to Leeds

Tags: uk, trains, buses, london, lhr

In reference to my earlier question - [earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163079/travelling-from-london-heathrow-airport-to-leeds-tempest-road)

I will be reaching at 10:15 am as I changed my travel date time.

1. Should I prebook national express coach to Leeds Station? Or should I reach there and book?Any benefits If I book early?
2. Another option is to take the underground till Kings Cross. Then get the LNER service till Leeds. For the underground tube tickets, Can i board any train towards Kings Cross or is there a train number or time for the underground tube?
3. For the above option (LNER) should I book early online towards Leeds? Again If I book a normal ticket is there a time or train number specific? I hope I can collect the tickets at the Kings cross station.
4. For LNER is it easy to locate the coach number? I mean I hope i will have enough time to locate the coach number in case the train just stops there for say 2 or 3 minutes(If origin station is somewhere else)

Comment: Too many questions in one. Please ask them separately. Although some of your questions already have answers elsewhere eg:
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130260/how-does-the-central-london-transport-system-work/
and

Comment: And this also answers some of your questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27730/compare-train-ticket-prices-in-britain

Comment: 4. Booking a seat on the train isn't often done: even if you do book a seat, someone might be in it. Unlike say Indian Railways where each carriage might have a paper fixed to it with the seating allocation. Note that trains are usually more expensive than coaches.

Comment: @WeatherVane many routes currently require you to make seat reservations with online bookings, even for flexible tickets (when of course you might not use the reservation).  This fails so often I've given up and go to the ticket office (I have an intercity commute)

Comment: @ChrisH do you mean under Covid-19 restrictions?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, filtered through the train companies efforts to keep occupancy down.  Bristol-Cardiff has been very quiet but some of the routes in South Wales are much busier. I don't know about further east or north

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A coach has a reasonable likelihood of being cheaper than a train, though a train will probably be the more pleasant option. Our roads are often congested so a train will usually be faster, and you'll have more space to move about, larger toilets, a place to buy snacks and light meals, etc.
2. London Underground is quite simple. If you're using a paper ticket it's just one charge no matter when you travel. If you're using a contactless card there are separate charges for peak time and off-peak but it'll charge you the correct one automatically depending on when you tap in. Depending on what ticket type you go for (see below) it may be worthwhile to buy a ticket that combines London Underground and mainline rail travel, in which case you won't need to worry at all about what time you catch the Underground train.
3. You basically have two options for ticketing: buy what's known as a "walk-up" ticket, which will be flexible and allow you to travel on any train (with some defined rules requiring you to avoid the peak hours, most likely), or buy an "advance" ticket which ties you to a specific train. A walk-up ticket is so named because you can walk up to a station on the day of travel and buy it. You can also buy them in advance online if you want to reserve a seat (this is not usually mandatory on UK trains, though it is right now due to COVID). They have names like "Anytime Single", "Off-peak Single", and "Super Off-peak Single" (note that as a result of a recent pilot scheme return tickets are no longer available for this route; buy two singles); most online train booking websites now do a decent job of making it clear you're buying a flexible ticket. Advance tickets can only be bought in advance (hence the name), and tie you to a specific train through the means of a mandatory seat reservation (without which the ticket is invalid), but can often be a lot cheaper than the flexible alternatives.

4. Yes, long-distance trains on that line all start their journeys at King's Cross, so you should have plenty of time to walk along the platform to find your coach and seat.

It's worth pointing out that right now there's major engineering works at King's Cross and so a reduced service is being run, so trains are likely to be busier than usual (though in practice I don't know how busy that is, due to the reduced travel from COVID). Depending on when you are travelling this might affect you, though I'd hope that the timetables online have by now been updated so any train you book on should actually exist... in the event that the train you are booked on doesn't exist and you have an advance ticket, you'll be entitled to travel on the next one by the same operator (LNER in this case).

Comment: The OP should also check https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/service_disruptions/currentAndFuture.aspx?TravelDate=17%2F04%2F2021&TOC=gr as there are major engineering works at KGX at the moment.

Comment: @mdewey good point.

Answer (score 4):

1. National Express tickets *may* be cheaper if you book in advance. Buying in advance guarantees you a seat on the bus, if you turn up on the day it might be sold out (that might be less likely at the current time).
2. London underground tickets aren't bound to a specific train. Get there, buy your ticket, and take the first train towards your destination.
3. For long distance trains, you can almost always get a cheaper ticket by booking in advance. Some tickets are specific to one train, others are flexible and allow you to take any train on a specific date (or any train outside of peak-time, or various other conditions). I don't think "a normal ticket" clearly refers to either type, both are common. In my experience, any website where you can book British train tickets always makes it clear which kind of ticket you are choosing.
4. This shouldn't be a concern. Kings Cross is the starting point for the line, so you should have plenty of time to find your carriage.

Comment: 3. The "advance" ticket class is always tied to a specific train but sells out.  Buying flexible tickets in advance isn't cheaper (there may be a few exceptions).  4. Anyway the carriages connect internally.  If you're short of time, get on and move through the train - tricky if you've got loads of luggage (Same username, not same user)